# Ionic 2 - 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, angular, jwt

Working on a new project with a very fresh install of ionic2 ,after install angular2-jwt I am getting this error:

```
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

D:\desenv\arquivos\workspace_inbit\medipop-parent\medipop-app\node_modules\angular2-jwt\angular2-jwt.ts:1
import {Injectable, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
```

To reproduce:

```
ionic start testapp --v2 --ts 
cd testapp
npm i --save angular2-jwt
```

and the app page:

```
@App({
    templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
    providers: [
        provide(AuthHttp, {
            useFactory: (http) => {
                return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
                    headerPrefix: '',
                    noJwtError: true
                }), http);
            },
            deps: [Http]
        })
    ]
})
class MyApp {}
```

Does anyone have a clue of how to solve this little puzzle?

Comment: I'm having the same problem here.. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Not yet Michel, basarat suggested to include a `module` inside tsconfig, but there was already one specified: `'module': 'commonjs'` @Michael

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line to your `ts` config:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module"
},
```

If this doesn't work, try with this config wich is working on my computer (`tsconfig.json`):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES5",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution":"node"
    },
    "files": [
        "angular2-jwt.ts",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "custom.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

You need to specify a `module` in your tsconfig or the command line. e.g.

```
'module': 'commonjs'
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: but what specific module? @basarat

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today on Ionic 2 beta 11 and for me it was coz of a (.js) extension file(user-data.js) instead of (.ts) file (user-data.ts) , so changing .js file extension to .ts solved my issue.